# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 eror DB::statement

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'authorization ewallet' at line 1 (SQL: create schema if not exists accounts authorization ewallet)

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        DB::statement('create schema if not exists accounts authorization ewallet');

    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        DB::statement('drop schema if exists accounts cascade');
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is

```
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('accounts');
}
```

And to do your up method

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('accounts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->uuid('id');
        ...
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

I would also recommend using the native way to create a migration file.

```
php artisan make:migration create_accounts_table
```

will automatically generate the required code to run a valid migration file. You can edit the scheme within the file as well.

You can read more about migrations and how to handle them here. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations

Comment: how about this     `public function up()
    {
        DB::statement('create schema if not exists accounts authorization ewallet');

    }`

Comment: I put that in my original answer.

Comment: Method Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint::uid does not exist.

Comment: verify that youre calling $table->UUID not $table->uid